# proving than every $2\times 2$ is similar to a united form

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, similar-matrices

I'm having troble proving this:

Let $A\in M_n(R). $ If $n=2$ and $A$ has exactly one eigenvalue $\lambda$ then $A$ is similar to $\begin{bmatrix} 
\lambda & 1\\
0 & \lambda \\
\end{bmatrix}$ or to
$\begin{bmatrix} 
\lambda & 0\\
0 & \lambda \\
\end{bmatrix}$

I did prove that if the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$ is $2$, then $A$ is similar to
$\begin{bmatrix} 
\lambda & 0\\
0 & \lambda \\
\end{bmatrix}$, but I'm struggling with the case when $A$ is not diagonalizable. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ be a eigenvector for $\lambda$ and $y$ be any other vector such that $(x,y)$ is a basis. Then, by changing basis you get :
$$A \sim \begin{bmatrix}\lambda & a\\0&\mu\end{bmatrix}$$

for some $a,\mu\in\mathbb R$. Since $A$ has only eigenvalue $\lambda$, we have $\mu = \lambda$. By rescaling $y$, we can set $a= 1$.

Comment: hey, thanks for the response! what do you mean by "changing basis you get"? by which basis? The same goes for "by rescaling y"?

Comment: Let $P$ be the matrix whose columns are $x$ and $y$. Then, the matrix $P^{-1}AP$ is the matrix $A$ "in the basis $(x,y)$"

Comment: Then do the same with $(x,by)$ for the right non zero real number $b$.