# Proof that a matrix is similar to one the following matrices.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, similar-matrices

I am required to prove the following statement: Let $A \in \Bbb M_2(\Bbb R)$ . Prove that if $A$ has one eigenvalue λ, then A is similar to $
    \begin{bmatrix}
    λ & 0  \\
    0 & λ  \\
    \end{bmatrix}$ or $
    \begin{bmatrix}
    λ & 1  \\
    0 & λ  \\
    \end{bmatrix}$
I was able to prove that if the geometric multiplicity of λ is 2 then $A$ is diagonalizable so it is similar to $
    \begin{bmatrix}
    λ & 0  \\
    0 & λ  \\
    \end{bmatrix}$. I was trying to find a way to prove that if the geometric multiplicity of λ is 1 then $A$ is similar to     $\begin{bmatrix}
    λ & 1  \\
    0 & λ  \\
    \end{bmatrix}$ but couldn't figure out how.
Assistance will be more than welcomed.

Comment: I think the basis will consist of an eigenvector $v$ (satisfies $(A-\lambda I)v=0$) and a generalized eigenvector $w$ (satisfies $(A-\lambda I)^2 w = 0$ and $(A-\lambda I)w \ne 0$).

Comment: Do you know about the Jordan canonical form?

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4150385/proving-than-every-2-times-2-is-similar-to-a-united-form?rq=1) should answer your question ? (Since the two questions are identical)